# Adding and removing classes in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, addclass

I tried to get it working, but can't figure it out.
Already searched topics, but either I didnt understand them or it wasn't asked. Could be both! :P

I just try to get the wrapper popped out, when you click on the "clickme"'s and if it is popped out, it should stay and just show the other content.
And if one of the "clickme"'s got clicked twice it should close...

HTML

```
<a id="nav1">Clickme</a>
<a id="nav2">Clickme</a>
<div id="navwrapper">
    <h1 id="dropdown1">Menu1</h1>
    <h1 id="dropdown2">Menu2</h1>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
document.getElementById("nav1").onclick=function(){
    var dropdown1 = document.getElementById('dropdown1');
    var dropdown2 = document.getElementById('dropdown2');
    var navwrapper = document.getElementById('navwrapper');
    if (dropdown1('not(.selected)') && navwrapper('not(.selected)')) {
        dropdown1.addClass('unselected');
        navwrapper.addClass('unselected');
    }else{
        dropdown1.addClass('selected');
        navwrapper.addClass('selected');
        dropdown2.addClass('unselected');
    }
};
document.getElementById("nav2").onclick=function(){
    var dropdown1 = document.getElementById('dropdown1');
    var dropdown2 = document.getElementById('dropdown2');
    var navwrapper = document.getElementById('navwrapper');
    if (dropdown2('not(.selected)') && navwrapper('not(.selected)')) {
        dropdown2.addClass('unselected');
        navwrapper.addClass('unselected');
    }else{
        dropdown2.addClass('selected');
        navwrapper.addClass('selected');
        dropdown1.addClass('unselected');
    }
};
```

CSS

```
#navwrapper.selected {
    display:block;
}
#navwrapper.unselected {
    display:none;
}
#navwrapper {
    background-color:#ff0000;
    transition: all 500ms ease;
}
#dropdown1, #dropdown2 {
    transition: all 500ms ease;
}
#dropdown1.selected, #dropdown2.selected {
    display:block;
}
#dropdown1.unselected, #dropdown2.unselected {
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: `dropdown1`, `dropdown2` and `navwrapper` are not jQuery objects. So, you cannot call jQuery methods on it

Comment: Also `dropdown2('not(.selected)')` will not work

Comment: Check out my answer, I checked it and it seems to be working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that how you wanted it to work? If yes I just changed the script to use jQuery only.
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/usascj4o/)

Try this code:

Javascript:

```
$( "#nav1" ).click(function() {
    var dropdown1 = $("#dropdown1");
    var dropdown2 = $("#dropdown2");
    var navwrapper = $("#navwrapper");
    if (dropdown1.hasClass( "selected" ) && navwrapper.hasClass( "selected" )) {
        dropdown1.removeClass('selected');
        dropdown1.addClass('unselected');
        navwrapper.removeClass('selected');
        navwrapper.addClass('unselected');
    }else{
        dropdown1.removeClass('unselected');
        dropdown1.addClass('selected');
        navwrapper.removeClass('unselected');
        navwrapper.addClass('selected');
        dropdown2.removeClass('selected');
        dropdown2.addClass('unselected');
    }
});
$( "#nav2" ).click(function() {
    var dropdown1 = $("#dropdown1");
    var dropdown2 = $("#dropdown2");
    var navwrapper = $("#navwrapper");
    if (dropdown2.hasClass( "selected" ) && navwrapper.hasClass( "selected" )) {
        dropdown2.removeClass('selected');
        dropdown2.addClass('unselected');
        navwrapper.removeClass('selected');
        navwrapper.addClass('unselected');
    }else{
        dropdown2.removeClass('unselected');
        dropdown2.addClass('selected');
        navwrapper.removeClass('unselected');
        navwrapper.addClass('selected');
        dropdown1.removeClass('selected');
        dropdown1.addClass('unselected');
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="nav1">Clickme</a>
<a id="nav2">Clickme</a>
<div id="navwrapper" class="selected">
<h1 id="dropdown1" class="selected">Menu1</h1>
<h1 id="dropdown2" class="unselected">Menu2</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: You're my hero! :)
I'm glad, that so many guys giving me so many answers. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Chimposant Glad to hear that :)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the class name of any element using the standard `className` property of `HTMLElement`. However, this gets/sets the full class name, everything between the quote marks. Example

```
<a id="one" class="hello world">
```

JavaScript:

```
var one = document.getElementById('one');
one.className = 'new world';
```

Now the HTML looks like:

```
<a id="one" class="hello world">
```

To add or delete **individual** classes on an element you can use the `classList` interface.

```
one.classList.remove('hello');
one.classList.add('new');
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Be aware that `classList` is not universally supported. If you need to support Internet Explorer 9-, this is no good. In this scenario you will need to create your own `addClass` and `removeClass` functions, or use a library like jQuery that provides them.

```
function addClass(el, name) {
    var regexp = new RegExp('(^| )' + name + '( |$)');
    if (!regexp.test(el.className)) {
        el.className += ' ' + name;
    }
    el.className = el.className.trim();
};

function removeClass(el, name) {
    var regexp = new RegExp('(^| )' + name + '( |$)');
    el.className = el.className.replace(regexp, '$1');
    el.className = el.className.trim();
};
```

Usage:

```
removeClass(one, 'hello');
addClass(one, 'new');
```

In general, be careful about mixing jQuery's API with native JavaScript/ECMAScript APIs. That is what is happening in your original code. You are applying jQuery methods to standard JS `HTMLElement` instances. This is a source of much confusion!

Comment: so I could just use `one.addclass('hello');one.removeclass('new');`?
Just for the knowledge. But thank you very much for the quick answer! :)

Comment: Er, no sorry: `addClass(one, 'hello'); removeClass(one, 'new');`. The HTML element is provided as the first argument to each of the custom functions I provided, the class name as the second. Answer updated.

Answer (score -1):

I am not a 100% sure what you want to accomplish, but my guess is you want 2 dropdowns with options inside of it?

My advice is to use Bootstrap (http://getbootstrap.com/) this is an awesome tool that uses Javascript and Jquery to accomplish this and much more like resposive websites and apps, faster reactions and searchable/sortable tables.

the jsfiddle for this is :

https://jsfiddle.net/wh64mLhu/

to break it down :

**Step 1**

Add Bootstrap CSS in your header like so :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
```

**Step 2**

Add the Javascript on the bottom of the body like so

```
<html>
      <head>
           <!-- Header Code + CSS Here -->
      </head>
     <body>
           <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
           <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     </body>
</html>
```

**Step 3**

Create the HTML body code whatever you would like to have, for example the JSFiddle I shared above.
This contains 2 Dropdown lists.

First you create a `<div>` to make clear you are going to create a new "division" in your page.
Than you add the `<Button>` with if you want an image using the `<span>`.
After you did this you create the list using `<ul>` and inside of it all the elements `<li>`.

I hope this helped and convinsed you to use Bootstrap :)

Comment: That's what I'm trying to avoid, but thanks anyways :)

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid using Bootstrap?

Comment: The person who minned me, care to elaborate?